# Allow file access only on android app and disable browser access using .htaccess or javascript..?

Tags: javascript, android, .htaccess

Can I disable direct url access using .htacces or Javascript..?

Assume my URL is http://example.com/js/example.js

I need to access Javascript file in Android app but I do not need to allow anyone to view that file in a browser whether anyone have the JS link.

Can I do this..?

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict access to it using a `.htpassword` file.

In your `.htaccess` file at the root of your project:

```
<FilesMatch "js/example.js$">
    AuthName "Application Only"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile /home/myProject/web/.myhtpasswd
    require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

In your `.myhtpasswd` file at the root of your project (or wherever you want):

```
test:$apr1$0ciO9Yg.$AUTSp18D2EWiZYN3u08HX/
```

You can use [online tools](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/) to create this file.

In your Android application you will be able to access this file by specifying the Authorization on your `HttpURLConnection` object. [See my other answer for more informations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37885434/5659190).

Comment: I tried the way but still I can access my file in the browser URL. I only changed AuthUserFile path to my path and created .htpasswd file in the way you showed me.